# Adding table rows and cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to make the page add rows and five cells to each table, however I'm having some problems. I appended the row first to the table then followed by looping through the and adding five cells to each row, however whenever I ran it in my web browser it produced this:

[image: this.]

I want the cells to be a child of the table row.

```
function addRows(ramnt) {
  if(ramnt > 0){
    var cellcount = 5;
    var tccount = 0;
    table.append('<tr>');
    console.log('Appended <tr>');
    while(tccount < cellcount){
        tccount = tccount + 1;
        table.append('<td id="Cell-' + tccount  + '" class="gencell"></td>');
    } 
    if (tccount = cellcount){
      table.append('</tr>');
      ramnt = ramnt - 1;
      addRows(ramnt);
    }
  }
}

console.log('Working');
var table = $('Table');
addRows(5);
```

Comment: What is `table`?? It looks defined wrong, I would use: `var table = $('#Table');`

Comment: It's not a class nor id, it's the base html tag.

Comment: So are you making a new `<table>` or calling an existing table in the rendered HTML?

Comment: Existing.... I'm not creating a new one.

Comment: How many tables exist in the HTML? I would assign a ID to the table and call it by ID or Class.

Comment: One. I just didn't think it was necessary to define it with an ID. I will do that now though.

Comment: You do not, you can call `$("table")` and it will find the one table. But if you have more than 1 table in a page, you've selected all of them with this code. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise making your function a little more dynamic. Here is what I would suggest:

```
function addRows(rc, to) {
  if(rc > 0){
    var cellcount = 5;

    for(var i = 0; i < rc; i++){
        var row = $("<tr>", { id: "Row-" + i });
        for(var c = 0; c < cellcount; c++){
            row.append("<td id='Cell-" + c + "' class='gencell'></td>");
        }
        to.append(row);
        console.log("Row " + i + " created");
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then you can pass the Number of Rows and the Table Object like so:

`addRows(5, $("table"));`

As I said, I would advise setting your table like so:

`<table id="myTable"></table>`

This way if you later add another table or do something differnt, you can still use the same code:

`addRows(5, $("#myTable"));`

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lysr2n5v/

You can take a bit further to write to function to accept X number of Rows, N number of Cells per Row, and the table Object: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lysr2n5v/2/

```
function addRows(rc, cc, to) {
  if(rc > 0){
    for(var i = 0; i < rc; i++){
        var row = $("<tr>", { id: "Row-" + i });
        for(var c = 0; c < cc; c++){
            row.append("<td id='Cell-" + c + "' class='gencell'></td>");
        }
        to.append(row);
        console.log("Row " + i + " created");
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `var row = $("<tr>", { id: "Row-" + i });` might not be a good idea, if you use this more than once, youll have invalid `HTML` with duplicate `ids`. You might also add logic to check the number of columns already present in the table and make sure you dont add more or less than are there now as that would not be valid either.

Comment: Good point. Could change it to a number of things, class or data: `{ class: "row", data-row-id: i }`. As OP pointed out, he's only using one table for now. So could also check the number of Tables already in play and append that into the ID: `{ id: "Row-" + i + "-" + $("table").length }`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `table.append('<tr>')`, jQuery inserts both opening and closing tags. I tried this:

[image]

Then you call `table.append('<td id="Cell-' + tccount  + '" class="gencell"></td>');`, which appends the `td` element at the end of the table, so it goes after the `tr` you appended before.

What you need to do is insert the `tr` as you did, but then select this `tr` and append into it. So something like this:
`table.find('tr:last').append('<td id="Cell-' + tccount  + '" class="gencell"></td>');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a row, append all the columns to that row, then append the row to the table like below.

**I would also recommend adding logic to check the number of columns already present in the table and make sure you dont add more than are there now as that would not be valid.**

With the below:

`addRows(5,5)` - will add 5 rows to every table on the page where each row will the same number of columns as the table currently has or 5 columns if the table doesnt currently have any columns

`addRows(5,5,'#myTable')` - will add 5 rows to the table with the id `myTable`  where each row will the same number of columns as the table currently has or 5 columns if the table doesnt currently have any columns

```js
function addRows(rowCount, colCount, table) {
    var $tables= table ? $(table) : $('table');
    $tables.each(function(){
      console.log('table');
      $this=$(this);
      colCount =$this.find('tr:eq(0)').find('td').length || colCount // limit the number of added cols to the numer already present
     for(r=0;r<rowCount;r++){
         var $row=$('<tr>');
         for(c=0;c<colCount;c++){
            $row.append('<td>');
         }
         $this.append($row);
      }
    });
}
addRows(5,5);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1"></table>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<table border="1"><tr>
  <td>some content</td>
  <td>some content</td>
  <td>some content</td>
</tr></table>
```