# How to auto increament serial number of row in html using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add rows of tables. I can't add serial number of new added rows.
i.e. I have to show serial number automatic increment while row is added.

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
        function addRow(dataTable) {
 var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
             var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(2);
                var colCount = table.rows[3].cells.length;
                for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
                    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[3].cells[i].innerHTML;

            }


    </SCRIPT>
```

Any idea? plz help

Comment: please indent your code properly to make it more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addCells(table, rows, cells);`

- table: A string that represents the id of the targeted table.

  - Ex. `addCells('dataTable',...)`
- rows: An integer of the quantity of rows to be appended to target tabel.

  - Ex. `addCells('dataTable', 4, ...)`
- cells: An integer of how many cells per row.

  - Ex. `addCells('dataTable', 4, 5)`

Each row and cell is assigned a unique id, this is the pattern:

- Row: `table id`+R+`row position`

  - Ex. `#dataTableR3` = 4th row of `#dataTable`
- Cell: `table id`+R+`row position`+C+`cell position`

  - Ex. `#dataTableR3C7` = 8th cell of 4th row of `#dataTable`

Note the offset in the numbers. This is due to the fact that the id system is 0-count (starts with 0 as the first number.) Check the dev tools - console to see all of the generated ids.

Here's the [jQuery version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35281653/2813224), from this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35280605/2813224). I don't consider it a duplicate since your question is more specific about an aspect of that previously mentioned question.

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');

btn1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var inp0 = document.getElementById('inp0').value;
  var inp1 = document.getElementById('inp1').value;
  var inp2 = document.getElementById('inp2').value;
  addCells(inp0, inp1, inp2);
}, false);


function addCells(table, rows, cells) {
  var T = document.getElementById(table);
  var R = parseInt(rows);
  var C = parseInt(cells);
  for (var i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    T.appendChild(row);
    row.setAttribute('id', table + 'R' + i);
    console.log('Appended row: ' + table + 'R' + i);
    for (var j = 0; j < C; j++) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      row.appendChild(cell)
      cell.setAttribute('id', table + 'R' + i + 'C' + j);
      console.log('Appended cell: ' + table + 'R' + i + 'C' + j);

    }
  }
}
```

```css
fieldset {
  margin: 20px;
}
table {
  border: 3px double blue;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter Table ID, Number of Rows, &amp; Number of Cells per Row</legend>
  <label for="inp0">Table</label>
  <input id="inp0" />
  <br/>
  <label for="inp1">Rows</label>
  <input id="inp1" />
  <br/>
  <label for="inp2">Cells</label>
  <input id="inp2" />
  <br/>
  <button id="btn1">Enter</button>
</fieldset>
<table id="t">
  <tr>
    <td>Table</td>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>is</td>
    <td>t</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="u">
  <caption>Table ID: u</caption>
</table>
```